# calling child_process.exec in Node as though it was executed in a specific folder

Tags: node.js, command-line, node-modules

I'm using the following to execute a CLI command in nodeJS

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec('foocommand', callback);
```

However, the foocommand is executing in the current folder node is running from. How can I make it execute as though it is being invoked from a different folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its in the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback):

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec('foocommand', { cwd: 'path/to/dir/' }, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a total expert but if its a cli then you want to be able to use stdin witch is not available with process.exec. Maybe you want to see if there is a programable interface for the cli?